# Grails 2.0: "No javascript provider is configured"

Tags: javascript, grails, view, grails-2.0

Hello I received the following error for some of my views:

```
2011-11-11 17:22:07,497 ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver - GrailsTagException occurred when processing request: [GET] /<appname>/test/list
No javascript provider is configured. Stacktrace follows:
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.exceptions.GroovyPagesException: Error processing GroovyPageView: No javascript provider is configured
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.exceptions.GrailsTagException: No javascript provider is configured
    at C__Development_bla_app_trunk_grails_app_views_test_list_gsp$_run_closure2.doCall(C__Development_bla_app_trunk_grails_app_views_test_list_gsp:72)
    at C__Development_bla_app_trunk_grails_app_views_test_list_gsp.run(C__Development_bla_app_trunk_grails_app_views_test_list_gsp:83)
    ... 3 more
```

I have tried the following:

in Config.groovy:

```
grails.views.javascript.library="jquery"
```

or

```
grails.resources.modules = {
  core {
    dependsOn 'jquery'
  }
}
```

in the layouts:

```
<g:javascript library="jquery" />
<r:layoutResources/>
```

in the GSP (with `grails.resources.modules` above):

```
<r:require module="core"/>
```

Nothing... always the same error. I am running out of idea and am hoping anyone else has one. 
How do I know I have jquery installed, are there other javascript libraries?

This is Grails 2.0.0.RC1

Thanks a lot

Jonas

Comment: looks like the jQuery plugin is not installed but are there any which come out of the box because with Grails 1.3.7 I did not need that plugin.

Comment: Also did

`<g:javascript library="application" />
<r:layoutResources/>`

didn't work

Comment: try installing the jQuery plugin yourself

Answer (score 1):

This will also happen if you remove the jquery plugin from grails.  It now comes configured by default with grails 2.x

You can declare this in the plugins section of `BuildConfig.groovy` like this:

```
plugins {
    // other plugins here...

    runtime ":jquery:1.8.3"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have installed jQuery and it works now.  Thought I get it to work with `library="application"` but never mind

Comment: Where are you using `library="application"`, in Config.groovy?

Answer (score 0):

For this specific problem if you are using version 2.0, you must run "grails install-plugin prototype" because grails 2.0 doesn't have prototype anymore.

This has been the solution for me. :)